# Count reduction using Thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Given some input keys and values, I am trying to count how many consecutive values with the same key exist. I will give an example to make this more clear.

Input keys: `{ 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1 }`

Input values: `{ 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3 }`

Expected output keys: `{ 1, 4, 2, 1 }`

Expected output values: `{ 1, 3, 2, 1 }`

I am trying to solve this problem on a GPU using CUDA. The reduction capabilities of the Thrust library seemed like a good solution for this and I got to the following:

```
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

struct count_functor : public thrust::binary_function<int, int, int>
{
    __host__ __device__
        int operator()(int input, int counter)
    {
        return counter + 1;
    }
};

const int N = 7;
int A[N] = { 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1 }; // input keys
int B[N] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3 }; // input values
int C[N];                         // output keys
int D[N];                         // output values

thrust::pair<int*, int*> new_end;
thrust::equal_to<int> binary_pred;
count_functor binary_op;
new_end = thrust::reduce_by_key(A, A + N, B, C, D, binary_pred, binary_op);
for (int i = 0; i < new_end.first - C; i++) {
    std::cout << C[i] << " - " << D[i] << "\n";
}
```

This code is pretty similar to an example from the [Thrust documentation](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__reductions.html#ga633d78d4cb2650624ec354c9abd0c97f). However, instead of the `plus` operation, I am trying to count. The output from this code is the following:

```
1 - 9
4 - 7
2 - 5
1 - 3
```

However, I would expected the second column to contain the values `1, 3, 2, 1`. I think the counts are off because the reduction starts with the first value it finds and does not apply the operator until it has a second value, but I am not sure this is the case.

Am I overlooking something about the `reduce_by_key` function that could solve this problem or should I use a completely different function to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your use case you don't need the values of `B`, the values of `D` are only dependent on the values of `A`.

In order to count how many consecutive values are in `A` you can supply a `thrust::constant_iterator` as the input values and apply `thrust::reduce_by_key`:

```
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>

int main()
{
const int N = 7;
int A[N] = { 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1 }; 
int C[N];
int D[N];

thrust::pair<int*, int*> new_end;
thrust::equal_to<int> binary_pred;
thrust::plus<int> binary_op;
new_end = thrust::reduce_by_key(A, A + N, thrust::make_constant_iterator(1), C, D, binary_pred, binary_op);

for (int i = 0; i < new_end.first - C; i++) {
    std::cout << C[i] << " - " << D[i] << "\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
1 - 1
4 - 3
2 - 2
1 - 1
```